# Determining stability of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

I'm working on a prey-predator model. I'm using the following system of differential equations for it:
\begin{align} x'&=-a_1x+a_2xy+a_3xz\\
y'&=b_1y-b_2xy\\
z'&=c_1z-c_2xz
\end{align}
Where $a_i, b_i, c_i >0$.

One of the stationary points is $P=(\frac{b_1}{b_2},\frac{a_1}{a_2},0)$.

**Question**: 
How can I determine the stability of this point $P$?

**Attempt**:

First I wrote the equation as:
\begin{align} \frac{\mathrm d \underline{v}}{\mathrm d t}=\underline{F}(\underline{v}), \hspace{10pt} \underline{v}=(x,y,z)\end{align}
I looked at the linearized ODE, and I found:
\begin{align} \frac{\mathrm d \underline{\hat{v}}}{\mathrm t}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & \dfrac{a_2b_1}{b_2} & \dfrac{a_3b_1}{b_2}\\
-\dfrac{a_1b_2}{a_2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &c_1-\dfrac{c_2b_1}{b_2}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\underline{\hat{v}}
\end{align}
The eigenvalues are $c_1-\dfrac{c_2b_1}{b_2}, \pm i \sqrt[]{a_1b_1}$. My problem is the pair with zero real part. I have learned a theorem that only says something when all eigenvalues have negative real part (then it's stable) or at least one has positive eigenvalue (then it's unstable). My other approach was Lyapunov's theorem. I found (with a little bit puzzling) the following Lyapunov function:
\begin{align}V(x,y,z) = a_2y+ b_2x  -a_1\left(1+\ln (y)-\ln\left(\frac{a_1}{a_2}\right)\right)-b_1\left(1+\ln(x)-\ln\left(\frac{b_1}{b_2}\right)\right)  \end{align}
Differentiating it brought me eventually to this:
\begin{align} V'=a_3b_2xz-a_3b_1z\end{align}
Now the only thing that I can say is that $V'$ is both positive and negative in every neighborhood of $P$, so the theorem doesn't say something about that case.

What I also thought about is to Taylor approximate the function $F$ till the second order term, like it can be done with one-dimensional ODE if the first derivative is equal to zero. But then here I get a matrix in a matrix (a tensor?) which is pretty vague. I can not visualise what is going on there, but if someone can explain how to do it that way, then you are welcome. I have read many articles about this problem on internet. I couldn't find something useful/understandable. Some are talking about manifolds, but I have not learned that yet. What I understand is that it is something like a solution curve.

I really couldn't sleep well because of this problem. Your help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**
I have realised that the function $V$ that I have used missed an imortant requirment, it was $0$ in all points $(\frac{b_1}{b_2},\frac{a_1}{a_2},z)$, so that was not a Lyapunov function. My new approach was to pick:
\begin{align} V(x,y,z)=\left(x-\frac{b_1}{b_2}\right)^2+\left( y-\frac{a_1}{a_2}\right)^2+z^2\end{align}
Okay, this one is Lyapunov for sure. I differentiate w.r.t. $t$ and get:
\begin{align} V'=(-a_1x+a_2xy+a_3xz)\left(x-\frac{b_1}{b_2}\right) + (b_1y-b_2xy)\left( y-\frac{a_1}{a_2}\right) +z(c_1z-c_2xz)
\end{align}
This is zero in $(x,y,z)=P$ but that is also a saddle point, which means that is both negative and positive in every neighborhood of $P$. I also tried some Lyapunov functions of the form:
\begin{align} V(x,y,z)=f(x-\frac{b_1}{b_2})+g(y-\frac{a_1}{a_2})+h(z)\end{align} 
where $f,g,z$ are all even functions that has minimum in zero. Examples that I have tried are: $-\cos(x), -e^{-x^2}$ and they also made $V'$ have a saddle point in $P$.

I also transformed everything to cilindar coordinates, but the equation that I have got was not so beautiful. I believe there is a way to prove the stability of this point.

Can you guys help me? I really don't know what to do after this.

Comment: Try simulating it, I suspect the solution may be closed orbits in phasespace.

Comment: @Lovsovs yes I think that too. But I want to determine the stability analytically.

Comment: You can combine the linearized equations ($\hat{v} = (\delta x,\delta y,\delta z)$) to get $\delta z \propto e^{(c_1 - \frac{c_2b_1}{b_2})t}$ and $\delta y'' + a_1b_1\delta y = -\frac{b_1 a_1 a_3}{a_2} \delta z$ and $\delta x'' + a_1b_1\delta x = \frac{b_1a_3}{b_2}\delta z'$. Since you know $\delta z$ you can easily solve these equations and see directly how a perturbation about the fixpoint behaves.

Comment: @Winther I get something like $y=A\cos(\sqrt{a_1b_1}t)+B\sin(\sqrt{a_1b_1}t)+e^{(c_1-\frac{c_2b_1}{b_2})t}f(\cos t, \sin t)$ where $f$ is a polynomial. For $x$ I get something similar. What I see now is that both $x$ and $y$ will not do crazy stuff,  if $c_1-\frac{c_2b_1}{b_2}<0$, right? But how did you get these equations, if I may ask?

Comment: Yes. If the perturbation is small initially it will remain small at all times given this condition. To derive it: your system reads $\delta x' = \frac{b_1}{b_2}\left[a_2\delta y + a_3\delta z\right]$ and $\delta y' = -\frac{b_2a_1}{a_2} \delta x$. Now take the derivative of the $y$-equation and use the $x$-equation to simplify (and vise versa). Another approach is using linear algebra: find the eigenvectors of the matrix and then expressing the initial condition in terms of these eigenvectors (and the eigenvectors evolve in time as $\propto e^{\lambda t}$ where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue).

Comment: @Winther Yeah now I see it. But isn't it true that the main point is that we cannot make conclusions about stability if the real part of some eigenvalues are equal to zero while some are less than zero?

Comment: Yes that is true. I forgot about the original system. The above only shows that the linear system is stable, but the stability of the linear system does not imply stability of the original system when one of the eigenvalues are zero. You might want to check out [center mainfold theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_manifold) which tries to answer the question is these cases.

Comment: @Shashi When you change to cylindrical coordinates, did you try $x = b_1/b_2 + \rho \, \cos{\theta}, \, y = a_1/a_2 + \rho \, \sin{\theta}, \, \, z=z$ (coordinates around the equilibrium point) because the stable direction of your flow is along the $z$ coordinate and your center manifold is tangent to $x, y$? What equations do you get if you do that?

Answer (score 2):

Heh, it's actually simpler than expected. The system is stable but
not asymptotically stable. Here is a rough sketch of a proof:

First, for simplicity, set
\begin{align*}
\beta &= \frac{b_1}{b_2}\\
\alpha&= \frac{a_1}{a_2}\\
\end{align*}
and then center your system at the equilibrium point $P =
\left(\frac{b_1}{b_2}, \frac{a_1}{a_2}, 0 \right) = \left(\beta,
\alpha, 0 \right)$ which means shift the variables as follows
\begin{align*}
x &\mapsto x + \frac{b_1}{b_2}\\
y &\mapsto y + \frac{a_1}{a_2}\\
z &\mapsto z
\end{align*}
The system becomes
\begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= \beta a_2  \, y  + \beta a_3 \, z + a_2
\, xy +  a_3 \, xz\\
\dot{y} &=  - \alpha b_2\, x - b_2 \, xy\\
\dot{z} &=  \left(c_1 - \beta c_2\right) z -c_2 \, xz
\end{align*}
which could also be reorganized as
\begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= \beta a_2  \, y   + a_2
\, xy + a_3(\beta + x) z\\
\dot{y} &=  - \alpha b_2\, x - b_2 \, xy\\
\dot{z} &=  \left(c_1 - \beta c_2\right) z -c_2 \, xz
\end{align*}
Now observe that the $x,y$-coordinate plane, also given by the
equation $z=0$, is invariant under the flow of the system, meaning
that the vector field is tangent to $z=0$. You can even check
directly that if you take a solution $\big(x(t), y(t) \big)$ of
the 2D system
\begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= \beta a_2  \, y  + a_2
\, xy \\
\dot{y} &=  - \alpha b_2\, x - b_2 \, xy\\
\end{align*}
then $\big(x(t), \, y(t), \, 0 \big)$ is a solution of the
original system
\begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= \beta a_2  \, y   + a_2
\, xy + a_3(\beta + x) z\\
\dot{y} &=  - \alpha b_2\, x - b_2 \, xy\\
\dot{z} &=  \left(c_1 - \beta c_2\right) z -c_2 \, xz
\end{align*}
All of this yields that the plane $z=0$ is a center manifold of
your system and the restriction of the system to that invariant
manifold is
\begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= \beta a_2  \, y  + a_2
\, xy \\
\dot{y} &=  - \alpha b_2\, x - b_2 \, xy\\
\end{align*} As you already know, the latter is a conservative system
(i.e. integrable, has a first integral) Thus, all trajectories on
$z=0$ are ovals (closed orbits, cycles) and consequently, all
orbits close enough to the invariant plane $z=0$ and in a
neighborhood of the equilibrium point $P$, will tend to approach
it more and more, as long as, the restriction $c_1 <
\frac{b_1}{b_2} c_2$ is satisfied. Thus, they will follow the
cyclic closed orbits on the invariant manifold. Hence, the
equilibrium point is stable, but not asymptotically.

Observe that whenever $c_1 > \frac{b_1}{b_2} c_2$ the equilibrium
$P$ is automatically unstable.

Here is the rigorous proof. The following theorem is a direct corollary from the theory of center manifolds ([see for example these slides](http://www.iki.rssi.ru/seminar/virtual/an_part2.pdf)). One can also prove it, although it requires some techniques from analysis. Notice that in this case, the center manifold is known explicitly and is $z=0$.

**Theorem.** *There exist two small open neighborhood $U, \, V \, \in \, \mathbb{R}^2$ of the point $0 = (0,0,0)$ and a smooth change of variables 
$$H \, : \, U \, \to \, V$$
$$H \, : \, (u,v,w) \, \mapsto \, (x,y,z)$$ of the form
\begin{align*}
u &= x + h_1(x,y,z)\\
v &= y + h_2(x,y,z)\\
w &= z 
\end{align*}
where the functions $h_1$ and $h_2$ are smooth of order at least two, so that $H$ transforms the system of ODEs
\begin{align}
\dot{u} &= \beta a_2  \, v   + a_2
\, uv\\
\dot{v} &=  - \alpha b_2\, u - b_2 \, uv \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ (1)\\
\dot{w} &=  \left(c_1 - \beta c_2\right) w - g(u,v)w 
\end{align}
into the original system of ODEs
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= \beta a_2  \, y   + a_2
\, xy + a_3(\beta + x) z \\
\dot{y} &=  - \alpha b_2\, x - b_2 \, xy \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ (2)\\
\dot{z} &=  \left(c_1 - \beta c_2\right) z -c_2 \, xz
\end{align}*

Since system (1) is definitely stable, but not asymptotically stable, system (2) is also stable but not asymptotically because (2) is obtained from (1) by the change of variables $H$ and any change of variables preserves stability (which is a topological property).

System (1) is stable because the first two equations are separate from the third. If you pick their first integral, let's call it $J(u,v)$, one can check directly that the function $J(u,v)$ is also a first integral of (1). Then, it is easy to prove the stability of (1). On each level surface $J(u,v) = const$, a general solution $(u(t), v(t), w(t))$ close to $w=0$, which starts from a point on the surface $J(u,v) = const$, stays on the surface $J(u,v) = const$ and because of the coefficient $c_1 - \beta c_2 < 0$ it converges to the solution $(u(t), v(t), 0)$, simply because $\lim_{t \to \infty} \, w(t) = 0$. However,
$(u(t), v(t), 0)$ is actually a closed cycle (a periodic solution). Therefore system (1) is stable, but not asymptotically, because   $(u(t), v(t), 0)$ does not converge to the origin.

Comment: I dont know if I can make this a formal proof. Even though we know that it goes to the plane $z=0$ when $t\to \infty $. The problems are still given how to find some $\delta>0$ such that : $\\ \Vert (x_0,y_0,z_0)- (\beta, \alpha, 0) \Vert < \delta \Rightarrow \Vert(x(t) , y(t) , z(t) ) - (\beta, \alpha, 0)\Vert<\epsilon \\$   for a given $\epsilon >0$. I don't know what the solution does before going to $z=0$ and even when it starts going to $z=0$ I don't know how it approaches the closed curves that are on the plane $z=0$.

Comment: How can I guarantee that the solutions can not go further than $\epsilon $ from point $P$?

Comment: @Shashi I don't know why you expect to find a simple, elementary argument. If at all possible, that would be a very lucky (maybe or maybe not educated) guess. Why waste your time if all the tools to draw a definite conclusion are at your disposal. Have in mind that determining the stability of an equilibrium with eigenvalues with zero real parts is one of the bigger challenges of the qualitative theory of dynamical systems. It is unreasonable to expect a simple solution. That is why people wrote articles on how to approach this problem and developed the center manifold theory.

Comment: @Shashi See my edit and you will find a rigorous argument, in the form of a theorem, that combined with my previous observations proves the stability of your system's specified equilibrium. That is how people prove these facts.

Comment: Yes, I have heard the same from my tutor, it would take serious work for this. However, I was wondering if a simple proof could be given. I have personally filled about 40 pages of proof attempts and got nowhere. Now I know for sure that it is not easy. Especially because of my lack of manifold theory etc.

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by "(1) is definitely stable"? I don't see how you conclude from the equation. Furthermore, what you got there is the same as what I got in my other post about neglecting high order terms.

Comment: I think seeing that needs an additional work. You might choose to not worry about it any further. However the answer would be still good for me and future askers. Although I don't need it per se anymore. I'm still very thankful for your help.

Comment: @Shashi No much work is needed. I added the argument. And it is rigorous. No need for epsilon delta definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the point is stable? If it is, then there exists a Lyapunov function that will show the stability. If the point is unstable, then you can use your Lyapunov function to show this via [Chetaev's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chetaev_instability_theorem).

Most likely, the stability of the point will change depending on the parameter values and you won't be able to show that the point is stable for any choice of parameters. I would try using the Lyapunov function you already have to show stability under certain sets of parameters.

Comment: I also thought that the parameters will change the stability, that is why I keep them like that, so I know for which sets the stationary point are stable or not. Can you explain what Chetaev's theorem is about? You suggested the function that I have used, but I don't see how I can make the point $P$ on the boundary of a set $G=\{ (x,y,z) \mid V(x,y,z)>0\}$

Comment: I meant to say that Chetaev's Theorem makes use of a Lyapunov function to show instability. I apologize if that came off as me saying that I was certain that your current Lyapunov function could be used to show instability. The theorem works by constructing a set $U$ inside some ball of radius $||x-P||=r$ such that along its boundary $V(x)=0$ , except at $||x||=r$. If $V'(x)>0$ in $U$ then the trajectory must leave $U$ through the ball boundary, and hence the trajectory leaves the ball too. Since this works for any $r$, the point is unstable.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand. However getting $V(x)$ equal to zero at the boundary needs puzzling. Do you have an idea? :)

Comment: The typical example given when explaining the theorem is given by using the difference of the squares of the states. In your case this would be $V(x)=1/2 [(x-\frac{b1}{b2})^2 - (y-\frac{a1}{a2})^2 - z^2]$. Then the boundary given by $(x-\frac{b1}{b2})^2 = (y-\frac{a1}{a2})^2$ and $z=0$ would yield $V(x)=0$. The analysis should be easier if you shift the P to (0,0,0) through a coordinate transformation.

Comment: Okay if we shift $P$ to the origin, then your suggested boundary is $x^2=y^2$ and $z=0$. I don't get how this can be a boundary of a neighborhood? And what did you mean with "except at $||x||=r$ "in one of your comments? Sorry for these many questions.

Comment: The set $U$ should look like a sector of a circle. Check out the figures in this two websites: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Chetaev_function https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Chetaev_theorems

Comment: @rpa Actually the equilibrium of the given system is stable.

Answer (score -1):

> I also transformed everything to cilindar coordinates, but the equation that I have got was not so beautiful. I believe there is a way to prove the stability of this point.

Easiest way to go for your system is indeed transform it into the cylindrical coordinates. To see the final picture, you should set $y=\rho \cos \theta, z=\rho\sin \theta$ and keep $x$ as is. If you assume that the parameter values are generic, then it turns out that there is no non-trivial equilibrium in this system. Which immediately means that the omega-limit sets are on the boundary of positive orthant. Moreover, the analysis of the system in cylindrical coordinates should show that one of the preys should always go extinct.

Comment: I have got: $\begin{cases} x'=x(-a_1+a_2r\cos\theta+a_3r\sin\theta)  \\ r'=r\cos^2 \theta (b_1-b_2x)+r\sin^2 \theta (c_1-c_2 x) \\ \theta '= \cos \theta \sin \theta (c_1-c_2x -b_1+b_2x) \\ \end{cases}$. But I dont know what to do with it. Could you explain more please?

Comment: Something is not correct here, the idea, if I remember correctly, is not to have any other variables in the equation for the angle variable. Anyway, you can find all the details in the book by Bazykin, Nonlinear Dynamics of Interacting Populations.

Comment: I tried again, but I get the $x$ again. I will try to read that book. Thanks!

Comment: @Shashi You have to change to cylindrical coordinates in the $z$ direction, not in the $x$ and the coordinates have to be centered at the equilibrium point.

Comment: @Futurologist I don't know how to proceed with that either. I centered it first. I get $r'= \left( \frac{a_2b_1}{b_2}-\frac{b_2a_1}{a_2}\right)r \cos \theta \sin \theta + a_3 r \cos ^2\theta +a_2 r^2 \cos^2\theta \sin \theta - b_2 r^2 \cos\theta \sin^2 \theta + \frac{a_3 b_1}{b_2} z \cos \theta$.... I don't see how the $r$ behaves in this either. Maybe nice to add: I could prove that $z$ tends to zero for $ t \to \infty$ but I can not make a good stability argument with that either...