# Why can we neglect high order terms when determining stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I'm here again busy determining stability of a stationary point of ordinary differential equation. I've asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2181158/determining-stability-of-ode) to get help with determining the stability and I wanted to avoid center manifold theorem, but a good stackexchange user suggested me to do it, so I have done it. However, it seems that it is not easy to learn the whole manifold theory in just two days or something. What I have focused on is the reduction principle. But there are still things that I don't understand and the most books and articles that are online do not explain it. After reducing the differential equation till something like:
\begin{align} x'= -x^3 + O(\Vert(x,y)\Vert^4),  \hspace{10pt} y'=-y^3 + O(\Vert (x,y)\Vert^4) \end{align}
They (without any explanation) say that the negative coefficient $(-1)$ implies stability and that the high order terms do not affect that. Okay I can understand it a little bit, but I would like to see a proof that this is actually true.

In my case I have got something less trivial than that after putting my system in a different coordinate for which the reduction principle can be applied and then  reducing it. I've got:
\begin{align}
x'=&\alpha y + \beta x y + O(\Vert(x,y)\Vert^3)\\
y'=&-\alpha x + \gamma x y + O(\Vert(x,y)\Vert^3) \tag{1}
\end{align} 
where the coefficient are positive. If I negelect the high order terms and just apply Lyapunov's second method on:
\begin{align}
x'=&\alpha y + \beta x y\\
y'=&-\alpha x + \gamma x y
\end{align}
Using the following Lyapunov function:
\begin{align}
V(x,y)=\frac{1}{\beta} x - \frac{\alpha}{\beta^2}\ln(\alpha+\beta x) - \frac{1}{\gamma}y-\frac{\alpha}{\gamma ^2}\ln(\alpha - \gamma y) + \alpha \left(\frac{1}{\beta ^2 } +\frac{1}{\gamma ^2} \right)\ln(\alpha)
\end{align}

I see that it is stable, because $V'=0$. Now my question is:

**Question: Can I neglect the high order terms in (1)? If yes, what is the proof for it?**

I would like to avoid proofs that need deep manifold theory in it. Can you also prove it without knowing anything about manifold theory, please? Furthermore, I don't need a fully written proof for it, just a sketch would be fine, so I fill in the details myself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you cannot neglect higher order terms in (1) because the first Lyapunov value depends on the coefficients at the terms up to the order 3. You can find all details in the book by Kuznetsov, Applied bifurcation theory. For a somewhat more abstract treatment you can try Arnold's Geometric methods in the theory of ordinary differential equations.

Comment: @Artem oh sorry , I didn't mention it, I have used Lyapunov's second method. Is that still not applicable here?

Comment: You can use whatever you'd like. For Lyapunov's second method you will need to find a special function $V$, however, there are no recipes to do this.

Comment: How do you "see that it is stable", exactly?

Comment: @Did I have added the Lyapunov that I have used. It derivative is equal to zero, so from there came my conclusion

Comment: Thus the equilibrium is **a center**.

Comment: @Did yes, but how I can I prove that I can say the same about the original equation (1)?

Comment: You cannot in general since infinitesimal modifications of some higher order can transform a center into an unstable focus.

Comment: @Did That is what I was afraid for. Is there some other methods that I can apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular case, the answer is definitely no, you cannot ignore the higher order terms. They are actually the most important predictors of the stability of the system. Your system is
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= \alpha \, y + \beta\, xy + f(x,y)\\
\dot{y} &= - \alpha \, x + \gamma\, xy + g(x,y)
\end{align} where $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are functions of order three and higher.
The truncated system 
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= \alpha \, y + \beta\, xy \\
\dot{y} &= - \alpha \, x + \gamma\, xy 
\end{align}
is actually integrable (conservative) which means that it has a conserved quantity (i.e. a first integral). That first integral is the Lyapunov function you have written down. For that reason, the orbits of the truncated system are closed ovals, following the level curves of the first integral (the Lyapunov function). Integrability implies structural instability. That is, the perturbing residual terms $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ generically destroy the conservative motion of the truncated system and the stability could go either way - you may end up having either a stable equilibrium point or an unstable one.

Bottom line: the expansion you have obtained so far does not give you any information as it is.

Comment: This is a special case of a fairly general concept: if the linearization has eigenvalues with all negative real part, then you have stability (independent of higher order terms). If the linearization has at least one eigenvalue with positive real part, then you have instability (though you may or may not have divergence, since divergence is not a local behavior). If the linearization has all eigenvalues with nonpositive real part but some with zero real part, then nonlinear corrections can still cause instability (depending on the system in question).

Comment: @Ian Yes, I am very much aware of these concepts. It is just that in this case we are not talking about linearization. We are talking about truncating a system and the situation is a bit more delicate.

Comment: Yes!! Now I got it. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Futurologist Are you sure this situation (where the leading order term is higher order than 1) can't be converted into a linearization situation by a suitable change of variable?

Comment: @Ian In general, it is not immediate or clear how (especially when the terms are resonant), and in this case there is a change of variables (in fact a polynomial one) that allows you to pass to the appropriate Poincare normal form. According to the Poincare normal form procedure, the monomial $xy$ is non-resonant and can be eliminated by a change of variables that is quadratic.

Comment: @Ian  In fact the first resonant terms of this system are all cubic. But definitely this stuff doesn't immediately follow from simple linearization results. As you can see, one starts applying Poincare's normal form theory just to give an argument that a relatively simple observation can also provide.